# Adding postback date to scripts?

Tags: php

I'm writing some scripts that are free, but only to members within my teaching program. What I want to do is check what sites have installed the script.

I was thinking of obfuscating some PHP that posts back to my server when installed so I can see the domain it's used on. Obviously the user could remove this, but if I was to put a few application variables in with the code it might stop them removing because doing so would break the script.

Any comments on this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to be sure, use something like Zend Guard (aka Zend Encoder) to encode the php file.

If you want some of it to be user-editable, just encode the core functions (along with your security check) in a separate file and then leave the higher level code open for them to tinker with/modify as required.